# How should we clean up and disambiguate the [find] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

[find](/questions/tagged/find) may be a problem.  It has a few possible legitimate meanings.

- "find" is a filesystem search tool on various flavors of *nix.
- "find" is also a filesystem search tool on various flavors of DOS and Windows
- "find" is also the name of a jQuery method.
- "find" also can be found in the name of a family of methods in ActiveRecord.
- "find" is also function in the C++ standard template library.

These seem to be perfectly legitimate uses.  Unfortunately, the word "find" is so horribly generic that it's being used by [*many* of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find+-jquery+-ruby-on-rails+-activerecord+-cakephp+-bash+-linux+-unix) to indicate that the asker is trying to find something.

**What can we do to clean things up?**

I can't see any hyphenated tags working here.  *nix `find` varies wildly in both origin (GNU, POSIX, BSD) and use.  ActiveRecord uses "find" as the first word in a method, so [activerecord-find](/questions/tagged/activerecord-find) probably won't work.  Only jQuery might be able to handle a [jquery-find](/questions/tagged/jquery-find) tag.  C++?  [c++-find](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-find)?  eww.  And Windows/DOS find?  ... yeah, [we have questions about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917732/using-find-and-if-exist-to-delete-a-specific-phrase-from-a-text-file).  Need I go on?

Comment: Thanks, added those.  Windows 7 also has a find tool.  Sigh.

Comment: I added a Tag Wiki. Hopefully that clears things up a bit. For the hyphenated tags, you can always add a reverse synonym to make the tag more discoverable, as in `[find-jquery] --> [jquery-find]`

Comment: If only users would read the tag wiki excerpt when tagging their questions.

Comment: For all filesystem finds, [find-tool] or [find-utility] would probably suffice.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

- Do nothing for the 3 bullet points, because the combination with other tags like **Unix, jQuery** will clarify the context
- Remove it as tag for questions, just searching for an answer
- In question about search-algorithms, replace `find` with `search`.

Other tags have the same ambiguity, like Float, which exists for C and C++ and Java and ... and computing in general.

Comment: Yes, but `float` really has only one meaning (more or less), regardless of the language. The current community gestalt is that tags have a single meaning, and your suggestion fails that test for bullet points 2 and 3.

Comment: A float can be 8, 16, 32, 64 bit and so on, depending on the language/platform. It can have additional methods like toString in Scala which don't exist in C. So looking just at the `Float`-tag isn't enough - the same phenomenon like for the find question: You might need consider additional flags to decide, whether you might be fit to answer the question.

Comment: Which is why I said "More or Less."  A file system tool and a jquery method are not at all the same thing.

Comment: I still don't get what you want. What shall be used, if the user searches for `find` in the context of `jquery`, or for `find` in the context of file search? Start an initiative to rename `find` here and there?

Comment: I am only pointing out that your assertion about tag ambiguity is not correct, as currently stated in your answer.  `float` works because everyone generally understands what it means.  `find` has multiple, distinct meanings.

Comment: Everybody understands find too, in the same way, as an C-Programmer does or does not understand Float-problems in Java, Scala, Smalltalk and so on. Sometimes he will, often he will not. Do you know every possible Float question in advance? `Float` works, because it is not the only tag. So does find.

Comment: The problem is not so much that you can't search for multiple tags, it's that you can't *follow* a set of multiple tags. At the moment, trying to follow the [find] tag because you want to know about new [jquery-find] questions will only lead you down a blind alley.  I could see following the [float] tag possibly being useful, but not the [find] tag.

Comment: Not if you're only interested in floats, related to C and C++. There is never a guarantee, that all questions, belonging to a flag, will match your hopes. I agree that `find` looks more problematic in this case than `Float`, but on the other side you can't force the people to search for `find`-topics with `unix-find`, people don't search the tag database before searching. You have to predict what the people will use, and for find, at least the unix file find, I predict, they just search for `find`. If you subscribe to Java, you will get many Android questions. Live is hard. :) Enjoy.