# What does it mean to "burninate" a tag?

Tags: support, tags, per-site-meta, terminology, burninate-system

There are requests to "burninate" tags all over the place!  What does this really mean; what happens to a burninated tag?  How is it different than removing a tag or black-listing a tag?  Would it be useful to include this definition in the [Stack Overflow Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trogdor#Trogdor_the_Burninator

Answer (score 128, accepted):

It's right there [in the Meme question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101417/159624). It means just deleting a tag. With fire.

> **Meme**: burninated
>
> **Origin**: Possibly [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) /
> [Strongbad: Trogdor the
> Burninator](http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail58.html)
>
> **Cultural Height**: 2010 - 2011
>
> **Background**: Used in reference to **deleting a tag** from the system.
>
> **See Also**: The official [burninated dragon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2qer.png), [Trogdor the Video Game](http://www.homestarrunner.com/trogdor.html).

In all seriousness, here's what usually happens:

A tag, when it's burninated, is removed from all questions that carry this tag. The entire history of the tag is wiped out, with no trace of the tag existing in revision histories. This will just remove the tag from the system, but it can easily be re-created by users [with the privilege to](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags).

If a tag is really bad, and chances are it'll be recreated soon, then it can be [blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blacklisted-tag). Only few tags are blacklisted, but there are many good examples, such as [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) on Stack Overflow, or the [pc](/questions/tagged/pc) tag on Super User, which are both [Meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and shouldn't exist.

To get a tag blacklisted, asking on the site's Meta is a good choice. This is nothing moderators can do—in fact moderators can't delete tags either—so it'll require community consensus and a developer to do that.

Comment: does it always imply subsequent blacklisting?

Comment: No, I think that only happens in rare cases or when you ask for explicit blacklisting.

Comment: Tags are normally blacklisted when there is evidence that the tag is likely to be created again in the future. It's completely at the discretion of Jeff, really.

Comment: So, what does deleting a tag mean, and how is that different from blacklisting?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You can delete a tag, which basically means removing it from all questions, however it'll still be possible to just go ahead and create the tag again. Usually deleting tags is enough, but for example, the `[homework]` tag has now been blacklisted.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to see that information in the answer, plus a definition of what blacklisted means for a tag, presumably that it can never be re-created. I came on this question because I wanted to know that precise information.

Comment: Is there any difference detween deleting a tag and burninating it?

Comment: @MickG My answer explicitly says "It means just deleting a tag".

Comment: @slhck your answer also explicitly says "with fire", which may imply that it's stronger than simple delete in room temperature, especially in context of blacklisting (brings to mind cauterization of a wound _after_ amputation to prevent future re-growth)