# Burninate [anti-golf]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

This one was flagged in a random tag wiki editing I was doing:

[image]

I totally agree it's a useless tag. If anyone is curious as to what anti-golf supposedly is, before putting on my burninate useless tags cap, I'd come up with this:

> Anti-golf is a hypothetical programming game, with the objective being
>   opposite to that of code golf.
>
> The real and popular code golf programming game, involves finding
>   solutions in code to problems using the minimal amount of characters.
>
> Anti-golf is a suggested counter model to the common game, by
>   implementing rules such as requiring longer code and ensuring the
>   program will fail if any single character is removed.
>
> First evidenced proposal of the game was in 2002, by Peter Makholm on
>   the Perl Programming lists.

Comment: `[anti-golf]` has no questions associated so it's target of the LOTDIC anyway.

Comment: Tricky to [burninate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640) a tag with [no questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anti-golf)

Comment: Are you suggesting black listing it as well?

Comment: I don't think it's at risk of becoming popular as I could only find one person talking about it on the interwebs over 10 years ago. But may as well blacklist it while burninating to save ever having to deal with it again.

Comment: Burninating a tag requires two Stack Exchange team members tend to a funeral pyre for nearly an entire 8 hour shift on top of Stack Exchange offices, which can only occur after getting the requisite permissions for an open burn in NYC.  We shouldn't be asking them to willy-nilly burninate tags that aren't problems.

Comment: hmm, that is a burden. How about if I supplied marshmallows?