# Explaining 'burninated' tag removal from question in edit notes

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits

I recently rolled back a tag change to [an old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4541156/480850), which [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168868) then informed me had been due to a "burninated" tag.  After searching Meta, I discovered [this explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120642/156412), so at least I understand *what* happened to my post and the [availability](/questions/tagged/availability) tag, if not why.

The explanation cited above states that "A tag, when it's burninated, is removed from all questions that carry this tag."  My question's revision description says "edited tags," which doesn't explain very much; I suggest adding more description to this automated tag removal, such as "Removing burninated tag 'availability'" with a link to an FAQ entry or the above-cited Meta answer on burninating.  Ideally, this should also include a link to the Meta question that caused the burnination.  If this kind of information had been posted, I wouldn't have rolled back the edit.

EDIT: According to @thegrinner, this is not an automated process.  Perhaps this feature request can include a Burninate tool for moderators.

Comment: I think that : DON'T EVEN THINK OF USING THIS TAG! It was burninated during the last major cleanup. is pretty clear lol

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd That's only visible if you click on the **already-removed tag**; and it doesn't explain burnination.

Comment: It's not an automated removal - someone is doing that by hand. The "Edited Tags" message is the default message when editing only tags and not the post proper. SO has no knowledge that it's being edited due to burnination versus normal tag editing. But you're right, it would be helpful to have a link back, though that's up to the person doing the burninating.

Comment: Burninate should not be automated, many times other tag should be used instead, per question, and only someone with enough skill can decide which.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: In this case the tag was crap and not replaceable with anything else, and so the burnination could be automated.

Comment: @Won't still, I don't think insta-kill is fitting.

Comment: Automated removals via an actual burnination or a merge do not leave any trace of the change in the revision history. The tag just disappears. ;) You're basically asking for a user to explain why they're removing a tag from however many questions they're retagging.

Comment: Addressing the other issue - *before* you rollback any edits to your post you should seriously consider why the edit was made. In this case that means researching those tags before adding them back in by rolling it back. I don't think this philosophy is spelled out anywhere, but it can be easily inferred if you are willing to assume that most editors are acting for the benefit of the whole SO community.

Comment: Given that this is not an automated process, this feature request has rather fallen apart. You have edited in response to this, but I'm not really sure what you're asking - you'd have to be more specific (and a complete revamp or a new question is usually preferred above a footnote).

Comment: @jball And if the editor has 70k reputation, (s)he usually knows what (s)he is doing. And you can @-reply an editor to ask about the reason for the edit.

Comment: @animuson I would have preferred not being notified; if I hadn't noticed the change, I wouldn't have been confused.

Comment: @Dukeling I didn't know editors receive notification from comments; is  that documented on the site?

Comment: @Dukeling I'll see if I can "revamp" the feature-request in light of new information about the process.

Comment: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).