# Why can't I nominate a tag for deletion when I review a wiki edit for it?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, review, tag-wiki

A user edits a tag wiki for a tag with 1 question on a whole SX site, and this comes up for my review. Now, the edit in itself may be fine, but what should I do if what I think should happen is for the tag to be deleted? There's no button for it.

Answer (score 5):

In order for a tag to be deleted you simply have to remove it from all the questions it is associated with. This process is known as [Burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag). 24 hours after that the system will delete the tag automatically provided no questions are tagged with it in the meantime.

Normally one would post on the site's meta first to check whether the site's community is supportive of such an action. Tag the meta question with [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) so that the community is aware.

Retagging is a manual process because each question must be assessed to see whether replacement of the offending tag with some other tag or tags rather than removal is the best course of action. Also if you retag something you're supposed to check that it doesn't have any other issues e.g. spelling/grammar.

Comment: ... and shouldn't such a suggestion be included as part of the tag wiki edit review page? Perhaps for tags with very few questions / first tag edit / empty tag wiki?

Comment: Because if a question has only one tag it needs to be tagged with something else and someone has to make that decision for each affected question.

Comment: What if the question has multiple tags?