# ​[how-to] get rid of this tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, retag-request, burninate-request

The [how-to](/questions/tagged/how-to) tag has no tag wiki but 37 questions covering widely different topics. I'd be inclined to associate 'how to' questions with [support](/questions/tagged/support) ("How do I use Stack Exchange feature X") but users have managed to tag [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)s, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s and even [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s with them.

I think [how-to](/questions/tagged/how-to) is a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), not unlike the [best-practices] tag mentioned there and should be [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/295232)/synonymized/merged. Thoughts?

---

Since I originally posted this, the tag has been removed from a few questions and as far as I can see it's safe to apply [support](/questions/tagged/support) to the remaining ones, as @PolyGeo suggested in the answer. That was previously [impossible for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk4nm.png) because "synonyms to required or moderator only tags can only be created by moderators", but @Sonic reminded me that circumstances have changed and I can no longer reproduce that error message, so they're merged now.

Comment: Since you're now a moderator, I think it will work this time without error.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of burninating it I suggest asking a moderator to merge the [how-to](/questions/tagged/how-to) tag into the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag with the latter being the master and leaving the former as a synonym to it.

If there are any questions for which a tag of [support](/questions/tagged/support) is unsuitable then re-tagging them prior to the merge would be appropriate.